# Organizations providing hosting for the technical infrastructure for FLOSS projects where the software hosted is itself FLOSS?

Tags: project-hosting

I've started a couple of small free open source software projects and am working on the technical infrastructure that supports communication, project planning, source code hosting, etc for these projects.

After looking around I've found some software which would be useful for supporting the projects, for example [Mattermost](https://about.mattermost.com/) and [GNU Mailman](http://www.list.org/), but i havn't found a good way to use them in practice.

I'm a developer (not a system administrator) and would like to spend my time on programming, rather than on setting up these systems on my own webserver.

I could use proprietary software (like google groups and slack) but would rather use free open source software.

**My question is: Is there any organization that provides *hosting for the technical infrastructure* for supporting open source projects, and *where the software that they host is itself open source?***

I'm looking for a place where a whole package of technical infrastructure could be hosted, including communication, project planning, source code hosting, bug tracking, etc.

I am ready to pay a small amount (max 5 euro/month) if necessary and if multiple projects are supported

Grateful for help and with kind regards,
Tord

Comment: @Mureinik a question on hosting infrastructure for open source projects does not seem off-topic to me.

Comment: @sunyata: I assume you mean where the tools used to provide hosting is itself free and  open source software, right?

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne: Yes, so for example they would host software like GNU Mailman (which is FOSS) rather than a closed source alternative, as well as other pieces of FOSS software that can be used for the technical infrastructure of a free software project. (At another level, the software which i am working on myself will be FOSS as well, but i guess it would be possible that the organization could provide hosting for closed source software, but still use FOSS software themselves on their server/servers)

Comment: @sunyata Thanks. I will come with as a good a list as I have...

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne: I've now updated the title of the question to make it more clear, thank you for bringing this up

Comment: @PhilippeOmbredanne: I'm reading your question again and I'm not sure that I answered your question because you asked about "the tools used to provide hosting". If you mean "low-level" things like Apache and MySQL then yes I would like that to be FLOSS but that wasn't what I was focused on (since I assumed - maybe incorrectly - that this software is FLOSS), rather I was worried about more "high-level" things like software used for team communication, project planning (maybe kanban boards) and so on (I call this the "technical infrastructure")

Answer (score 3):

Sure, there are a bunch.  Some are better than others for certain things, and some omit features that you may or may not need, so there's no one direct answer.  But here are a few useful things to look into:

There are a variety of [software forges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forge_(software)), and some services that will host them for you, too.  [Sourceforge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge) is probably the most well-known, but there's also [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab), [Bitbucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitbucket), [Savannah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Savannah), and a few others.

[Librelist](http://librelist.com/) and Google Groups provide free mailing list hosting.

[Freenode](https://freenode.net/) has been the IRC network of choice for open-source software for a long time.  [Gitter](https://gitter.im/) is a more modern alternative.

[Bintray](https://bintray.com/) is a nice service for hosting binary downloads.

Comment: The question is asking for open source services. Not Google Groups and GitHub!